# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I think the idea is to prove that sequence of partial sums of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$ is bounded. If that was the case we could use Dirichlet's test since $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is obviously monotone and approaches $0$. I tried writing $\sin\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$ as $\sin(n-1+\frac{2}{n+1})$ and $\sin(n+\frac{n-1}{n+1})$ but it didn't lead anywhere except that  $\sin(n+\frac{n-1}{n+1})$ could be seen  as $\sin(n+1)$ intuitively for big $n$ and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(an+b)$ is bounded.

Comment: Can you state the conditions of Dirichlet's test? It's not clear to me that you're clear on what needs to be done.

Comment: if sequence of partial sums of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty an$ is bounded and bn is monotone and approaches 0 then series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty an bn$ converges

Comment: Right, which is your $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: Separately, note that $\frac{n^2+1} { n+1} = n-1 + \frac{2}{n+1}$.

Comment: sin is an and $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} is  bn$

Comment: Right, so you want to show that partial sums of $\sin \approx n-1$ is bounded, which you've just edited in (and which is why I was previously saying you didn't have the right conditions). $\quad$ So now, how can you rigourize that approximation?  Hint: $|(\sin x)' | \leq 1$.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting and it takes  awfully long to do so so I skipped writing few things. What does rigourize mean?

Comment: @klop "make rigorous"

Comment: From your writeup, you're left with showing that  A/ $ |\sum ( \sin (n^2+1) / (n+1) |$ is bounded, and are aware that B/ $ | \sum \sin (n-1) | $ is bounded. I'm saying all that you need is C/ $ |(\sin x)'| \leq 1$ (alongside B), to prove A. $\quad$ Though, thinking about it again, we might need a bit more machinery.

Comment: I don't see how C helps me

Comment: still haven't got anywhere, can I get another hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Use the angle sum formula: $$
\sin\left(n+\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right) = \sin(n)\cos\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)\cos(n)
$$
that way you can split the sum into two.

Next, show that the sequences $\frac1{\sqrt n}\cos\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)$ and $\frac1{\sqrt n}\sin\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)$ are monotonic for sufficiently large $n$, and both go to $0$.

Finally, to use Dirichlet's test, you need that $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n)$ are bounded. There's a number of ways to show that. One is to use Euler's formulae to turn them into sums of complex exponentials, which are actually geometric series and therefore the partial sums have a (bounded) closed form.

Comment: oh, that works too. I already got an answer on the other question so I dont know what to do. I'll accept the answer here but you can copy the answer there if you want so people can see it easier in the future. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: this is why it's bad practice to post the same question twice :P anyway the other answer is probably easier than mine.